# Raspberry pi 3 ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Tags: google-chrome, raspberry-pi

i am new to raspberry pi. my rbpi3 can't connect to the internet and chrome kept displaying ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED. the raspberry pi is connected in my laptop via Ethernet cable. i use advanced ip scanner, putty and xming. I already shared my wifi connection to other networks connected through my laptop but nothing works. I also tried to use monitor and connected my rbpi to my router using the Ethernet cable. The wifi symbol can be seen at the top right and it is connected but when i open chrome, it still shows ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION. i don't know pls help me T^T